# jetpack is in offline mode in wordpress. how to enable it and connect to our wordpress.com account

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jetpack

When I am done with jetpack plugin installation. My jetpack dashboard shows the popup like jetpack is offline you can't use some feature in disable mode. How to fix this problem as well as how to connect with my Wordpress.com Account?

Comment: You need to link Jetpack with your Wordpress account. Create a new one on Wordpress website https://wordpress.com/start

Answer (score 1):

wp-config.php -> wp_environment_type:local -> change production.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already account on jetpack then try to deactivate and delete the plugin then reinstall and activate.
..
.
If you still facing the error then ping me.

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactlly a error this is the mode which u have bydefault because of your jepack account not link or in activate state with WordPress. You can use only limited services because of local hosting if go through online then you will be able to all sevices of jetpack